# Block expanding of Expandable List View on long click

Tags: java, android, android-studio, expandablelistview, onitemlongclicklistener

I am developing an android application, in which I am using `Expandablelistview` to show some data. Currently the list view will expand on both clicking on group and on releasing after long click. But, I need to prevent from expanding the `Expandablelistview` on long click.

My code segment looks like this:

```
elvItemList = (ExpandableListView) root.findViewById(R.id.elv_item_list);
elvItemList.setOnGroupClickListener(this);
elvItemList.setAdapter(smListAdapter);
elvItemList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id) == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
            Utils.logit("SMLOG", "Long button pressed");
            //
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP` is the id of a group, change it to
`ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD` and you can manipulate with longclicks on group childs.

Something like that:

```
elvItemList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id) == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
// Your code with group long click
return true;
}
return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void stopExpandOnLongClick()
{
    expListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            boolean checkClick=false;
            long packedPosition = expListView.getExpandableListPosition(position);

            int itemType = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(packedPosition);
            int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(packedPosition);

             /*  if group item clicked */
            if (itemType == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
                //  ...
                if(expListView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It's normal group collaspe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This Grouo is not going to expand on long click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //you can put your logic when you long press on Group header
                    checkClick=true;
                }
            }
            return checkClick;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
expandableListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            return true; // Change return false; to return true;
        }
    });
```